# cant get specific element with html.find in Python

Tags: python, python-requests-html

I am pretty new to coding and doing a beginners course in Python.
working with the "requests_html" library I am attempting to get the name of a pokemon from a specific website as shown in the code below. A simple function should retrieve the name of the pokemon selected by the "index", and added to the "pokemon_base" dictionary. But instead it is getting a huge array of information.

Below I have attached a screenshot of the class that should be getting from the website and another screenshot of what the code in the course video looks like.

Thanks in advance!

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

pokemon_base = {
    "name": "",
    "current_health": 100,
    "base_health": 100,
    "level": 1,
    "type": "",
    "current_xp": 0
}

URL_BASE = "https://www.pokexperto.net/index2.php?seccion=nds/nationaldex/movimientos_nivel&pk="

def get_pokemon(index):
    url = "{}{}".format(URL_BASE, index)
    session = HTMLSession()

    new_pokemon = pokemon_base.copy()
    pokemon_page = session.get(url)

    new_pokemon["name"] = pokemon_page.html.find(".mini", first=True).text
    print(new_pokemon["name"])
    return new_pokemon

print(get_pokemon(4))
```

[image: My result]
[image: Course result]
[image: Website]

Comment: What huge array are you getting? It just says `Bulbasaur`

Comment: Sorry, that one is the screenshot from the course video. Updated now

Comment: You need to show the problem result.